# Nested ipairs for basic hit detection

Tags: collision-detection, lua, love2d

I'm developing my first game using *Löve*, the game is a basic Asteroids clone. Everything is going well so far, until I decided to actually add asteroids.

I'm trying to make a basic hit-detection that checks if a bullet is within the boundaries of an asteroid, then deletes both of them.

The issue is that if I do this:

```
for i, v in ipairs(bullet) do
    for i, ast in ipairs(asteroid) do
        i fv.y < 20 + ast.y and v.y > ast.y - 20 and v.x < 20 + ast.x and v.x > ast.x - 20 then
             table.remove(asteroid, i)
             table.remove(bullet, i)
        end
    end
end
```

It deletes the asteroid that was hit, but a random bullet rather than the bullet that hit the asteroid. If I split the code, it only deletes either the asteroid or the bullet, whichever is run first. If I reverse the ipairs, the bullet disappears, but a random asteroid is removed instead of the one that got hit.

Tl;Dr, How do I properly use nested ipairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a typical starters error: you chose both loops iteration variable to be the same, so they modify each other.

You should always choose nested loops to use a different iteration variable(usually called i, j, k), otherwise things will get messed up. In other languages completely, but here you got the two objects already and using the keys only to remove, so only the removal part got messed up.

The correct code should be:

```
for i, v in ipairs(bullet) do
    for j, ast in ipairs(asteroid) do -- instead of i you have j here
        i fv.y < 20 + ast.y and v.y > ast.y - 20 and v.x < 20 + ast.x and v.x > ast.x - 20 then
             table.remove(asteroid, j) -- changed here to j as well
             table.remove(bullet, i)
        end
    end
end
```